# An issue with paralellising function broadcasting over a mesh using dask

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask

I am looking to parallelise a function which takes multiple 1-dimensional ranges (which are of the form `np.linspace(x,y,t)`) of numerical input values (this is variable, but lets say it takes five), creates a mesh out of these ranges, and then evaluates some (5-dimensional) cost function for this over this mesh. In its current form it looks something like this:

```
def func_5d(a,b,c,d,e):
    return a + b + c + d + e

def range_search(a_range, b_range, c_range, d_range, e_range):
    mesh = itertools.product(a_range, b_range, c_range, d_range, e_range)
    func_eval = map(lambda x: (func_5d(np.array(x)), x), mesh)
    return func_eval
```

So, here I would be looking to parallelise the function `range_search` using dask. Ideally, this would be done by creating a dask mesh, which could then be chunked, and then mapped through to our cost function using either multi-threading or multi-core processing. Looking through the dask documentation, it does not appear that dask.array contains any suitable mechanism to achieve this. There is a dask.array.meshgrid function, extended from the numpy library, but this does not support chunking. Additionally, dask.array does not seem to contain a paralellised map function. However, there is one in dask.bag. But the documentation seems to suggest that dask.bag is used only as a module to carry out preliminary processing of raw data (in formats such as CSV, JSON, etc). Dask.bag objects do also have a method called product() which seems to imitate the itertools.product; however this only takes one other dask.bag object as an argument. So meshing 5 arrays required this method called to be stacked (4 times), which aside from being hideously ugly, is also inefficent when the number of inputs is variable.

From here, I don't really know where to go. I have worked through the Jupyter Notebooks that dask have put together, but they do not seem to hold an answer to my question. Any suggestions on the best approach to paralellising functions of the above form would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Numpy Slicing for this

```
a[:, None, None] + b[None, :, None] + c[None, None, :]
```

You will want to make sure that your input vectors are chunked finely enough that the products of them will still fit comfortably in memory.

Comment: So this will work if the number of input lists is fixed, say three for your example, such that we can pre-specify the slicing indexes (`[:,None,None], [None,:,None], [None,None,:]`). But how would I use this approach such that it could any number of input lists? Really this amounts to "how do I create lists of a given length consisting of a single `:`, and the rest of the entries occupied by `None`. So if we had two input lists, we would expect the output to be `[:,None], [None,:]`, etc...?

Comment: You would construct a tuple that included `None` values and `slice(None, None)` values (this is `:`) and then pass that tuple into the slicing syntax.